# What is an example of a query that needs both WHERE and HAVING clauses?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not asking what the difference between the two clauses are. I understand that the WHERE clause searches within rows in a table and that the HAVING clause searches within the items that are grouped in the select statement.

Example:

`SELECT x, Count(*) 
 FROM table 
 WHERE x IS NOT NULL 
 GROUP BY x 
 HAVING Count(*) > 1 
 ORDER BY x`

Returns the same as

`SELECT x, Count(*) 
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY x 
 HAVING x <> NULL 
        AND Count(*) > 1 
 ORDER BY x`

Can the HAVING clause return the same results without the WHERE clause every time such as in this example, or is there a time that a WHERE clause is going to be necessary? Or is this just a matter of efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the where clause to filter by any column in the table before the grouping is done. E.g.

```
SELECT  x, COUNT()
FROM    table
WHERE   y IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY x HAVING COUNT() > 1
ORDER BY x
```

So the answer is absolutely yes, you need the where clause sometimes. And as Rahul points out, even in your examples I would prefer the one with the where clause.

Comment: But why would you need to from a results perspective? Won't you always get the same result?

Comment: No. If you remove all rows where y is not null, that could reduce the count.

Comment: Right, I see it now. I was ignoring the y and confusing it for x. Thanks!

Comment: I like this as an answer more because it actually shows an example of why it would be necessary and not just how it works, but thanks @Rahul for your answer too

Answer (score 1):

In your first query, `WHERE x IS NOT NULL` filtering out all rows where column `x` have null values and then performing the grouping.

Whereas, in second query you are first performing the grouping and then applying the same filter.

I would prefer the first one, filter out the rows not needed and then perform the grouping.

Comment: makes a good point about filtering before grouping, but there are some situations where it is necessary to filter after the grouping - for example when you have a count of elements in each group and only want to return groups with more than 1 member.

Comment: @deadflowers, per your posted example it's efficiency but there are times when you need the filter in having as pointed by Greg in above comment.

Comment: That makes sense, from now on I'll picture the WHERE clause as a filter and the HAVING clause as a grouper, which is what I thought at first but I couldn't picture an example where the results would be different.

Comment: Sorry, first time ever asking a question on here, thought it was determined by votes.